# J2ME emulator that works for ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, java, j2me

Is there any J2ME emulator like JBed for ICS? I've found a ton of tutorials [like this](http://jimmod.com/blog/2012/03/got-android-gingerbread-and-want-to-run-j2me-jadjar-emulate-j2me-app/) but  as far as I know, all of them are exclusively for Gingerbread and below.

**P.S.** I already tried [J2ME Runner](http://www.netmite.com/android/) but whenever I submit my JAR and JAD files for conversion on their site, it would hang up and send me a converted .APK with corrupted content so that cancels out that method too.

Comment: Think this should belong on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: How so? This isn't programming-related. I believe it's an end-user question since I'm wanting to run old Java games from my Nokia phone on my Android phone.

Comment: Are you sure you get corrupted content? Do you have the J2ME Runner inside your phone?

Answer (score 0):

With Android's Gingerbread builds, it was built using the Java 1.4 components, ICS and later are built using Java 1.5+.

Nokia uses Symbian specific Java midlets and JAR's written using Java 1.2 or 1.3 ME edition.

And from the tutorial linky, there is no mention of specifically running Nokia's apps on it.

Rather, the impression I get, is Java agnostic JAD/JARs/Midlets not tied to any platform.

In your case, Nokia apps are specifically for Nokia which I guess is why it failed.

Comment: I've also tried a Java game that ran quite well on a Samsung Corby 2 so I doubt that that's the case. I'm convinced that the problem I'm having is because of the lack of ICS support though. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a working one called phoneME. It was written for Android 2.1-2.2, so don't expect it to be stable. Here's download link:

http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/10

Also, emulator doesn't appear to like paths with spaces and to run JAR files directly, so you need to make a JAD file. Sorry for my bad English.